# HT_condor removing/putting on hold only jobs with a certain batch_name

Tags: condor, htcondor

Suppose I am running 200 jobs on HT_Condor with `BATCH_NAME = "Ranking_noVV"`, and each job has a different `JOB_ID`, starting, for instance, at `4333042` and ending at `4333242`. I would like to remove or put on hold all the jobs with `BATCH_NAME == "Ranking_noVV"`. Is it possible?

I tried the option `-name` as suggested on the [HT_Condor documentation](https://htcondor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/man-pages/condor_rm.html), but that option doesn't refer to the `BATCH_NAME`.

In the meantime I am running other jobs with different `BATCH_NAME` and `JOB_ID`, so the `condor_rm -user` isn't an option.

Thank you for you help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
condor_rm -const 'JobBatchName == "Ranking_noVV"'

or

condor_hold -const 'JobBatchName == "Ranking_noVV"'
```